# if statement is giving me some trouble

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, if-statement

For some reason, this if statement is giving me an "Expected : before ] token.

```
    if ([ [mine commodity] isEqualToString:@"Gold"] && [gold == YES])
    {
        [tempMine setAnnotationType:iProspectLiteAnnotationTypeGold];
        [mapView addAnnotation:tempMine];
    }
```

is there some typo here that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[gold == YES]` should be `gold == YES`. The square brackets are for method invocations, and `==` isn't a method.